# How to round Milliseconds to Minutes in a Time String?

Tags: javascript

how to round variable

```
var x = '00:00:24.320';
var y = '00:00:19.968';
```

to get final result

```
x = '00:00:24';
y = '00:00:20';
```

?

Comment: So split, convert to number, round, put back together.

Comment: @Szymon: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please **[take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)**, visit the **[help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help)** and read especially the page on **[how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Comment: @epascarello: that is decidedly non-trivial when you might have to overflow seconds to minutes and minutes to hours, as str demonstrated/

Comment: Close voters: this is not a duplicate of that question.  There is much more going on with dates!

Comment: @ScottSauyet okay, so than you detect if > 60 and update up the chain....

Comment: @epascarello: it's not very difficult, but harder than suggested by your pithy comment, that's all.

Comment: @str True, due to the formatting I misread the desired output. Close vote retracted.

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use the [built-in date functionality of JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```js
function roundToSecond(time) {
    const pad = arg => `${arg}`.padStart(2, '0');
    const date = new Date(`1970-01-01T${time}Z`);
    date.setMilliseconds(date.getMilliseconds() + 500);
    return `${pad(date.getUTCHours())}:${pad(date.getUTCMinutes())}:${pad(date.getUTCSeconds())}`;
}

console.log(roundToSecond('00:00:24.320'));
console.log(roundToSecond('00:00:19.968'));
console.log(roundToSecond('23:59:59.501'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Split, use `toFixed()` and then combine

```js
let x = '00:00:24.320';
let [first, second, last] = x.split(':');
last = Number(last).toFixed(0);
x = `${first}:${second}:${last}`;
console.log('x: ', x);
```

Comment: Dates and times don't follow mathematics. This will break for anything similar to `00:00:59:500`.